# Find controller method for API endpoint in asp.net core app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Suppose I have a list of API end points. And I need to make changes to behavior of an endpoint. What would be the fastest way to identify controller method for the endpoint? I can think of following approaches.

1) Look at path in the endpoint and find controller. Put break point in the controller. This is manual approach.

2) For one project, I had a custom middle ware. I used to put the break point at call to '_next' method  in the middle ware. Stepping into the call takes you to the controller constructor and then controller method. This works well as long as you have custom middle ware for the project.

Is there any other way to find controller method? I want to stop execution at the beginning controller method call.

Comment: If i understand correct, You have url adress and You want to find which action in controller it hits? 
Where is problem? 
Just look at Your routing, if it's attribute routing then search for attribute in controller, if its convention based than look at convention.

Comment: Yes that is correct. i understand what you are saying. I was just wondering if there was a functionality in visual studio which allowed it to pause execution when it entered any controller action.